# How to join queries to show result in one table

Tags: sql

How we can join these below queries to show result in one table. its work separately  but when i try to join it it shows error.

there are two table. 1) plant. 2) visit. i need to count total plants as per employee group wise and want to count visit as well as.

```sql
SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(*)
FROM plant      
GROUP BY plant.employee_name;

SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(*)
FROM visit      
GROUP BY employee;
```

Comment: Can you include the combined query that you tried, and the error message that you get?

Comment: Join how? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images.

Comment: `") as $row)` is invalid SQL

Comment: What RDBMS is this? mySQL, SQL Server? oracle Postgresql? and version...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union command to combine both result queries to one if they have the same output schema

```
SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(*)
FROM plant      
GROUP BY plant.employee_name

UNION

SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(*)
FROM visit      
GROUP BY employee
```

since both your queries return one string and one number this should give your desired result

Comment: i entered as 

SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(p_id)
FROM plant      
GROUP BY plant.employee_name; 
UNION
SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(v_id)
FROM visit      
GROUP BY visit.employee; ") as $row)

but its not working. not getting result after union query

Comment: Try entering(removed the ; and the ") as $row) ): SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(p_id) FROM plant GROUP BY plant.employee_name UNION SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(v_id) FROM visit GROUP BY visit.employee

Comment: Edited my Post to display the query as it should be, it had some formatting errors which resulted in faulty sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming employee & employee_name are same data type):

```
select sum(case when a.[field name] is not null then 1 else 0 end) as plant_count, 
sum(case when b.[field name] is not null then 1 else 0 end) as visit_count, 
a.employee_name,  
b.employee

from plant as a 
outer join visit as b
on a.employee_name = b.employee

group by 
a.employee_name,  
b.employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume the employee and employee_name contain the same data?  Can we assume a record always exists on both sides (if not is it always on one side or the other or do we need to use a full outer join here?)  which may not be supported on all RDBMS...

```
SELECT coalesce(Employee_Name,Employee), EmpPlantCount, EmpVisitCount
FROM (SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(*) EmpPlantCount
      FROM plant      
      GROUP BY plant.employee_name) A
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(*) EmpVisitCount
                 FROM visit      
                 GROUP BY employee) B
 on A.Employee_Name = B.Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information about employees, you should source your results by selecting first from the `employee` table (assuming you have one).  Something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  e.employee_id, 
  COUNT(p.employee_id) AS plant_count,
  COUNT(v.employee_id) AS visit_count
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN plant p ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id -- Get plant info
LEFT JOIN visit v ON e.employee_id = v.employee_id -- Get visit info
GROUP BY e.employee_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.employee_name, v.employee),
       p.num_plants, v.num_visits
FROM (SELECT plant.employee_name, COUNT(*) as num_plants
      FROM plant      
      GROUP BY plant.employee_name
     ) p FULL JOIN
     (SELECT visit.employee, COUNT(*) as num_visits
      FROM visit      
      GROUP BY employee
     ) v
     ON p.employee_name = v.employee;
```

This assumes that `employee` and `employee_name` are the same thing (they should have the same name).

Note that you want to do the aggregation *before* joining.